# Mostrar registros por años en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

he estado intentando varias formas de como mostrar una lista de registro en este caso de empresas por años, de momento he conseguido mostrar las empresas creadas en este año, por medio de:

```
def self.year
   where(created_at: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year..Time.zone.now.end_of_year)
end
```

Pero no logro conseguir que me muestre los registros menores al año actual, intentado crearlo de esta forma, pero no me imprime nada:

```
def self.before_year
   where(created_at: Time.now - 1.year)
end
```

Espero puedan darme una sugerencia amigos, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where(created_at: Time.now - 1.year)
```

Está indicando un fecha exacta. Estás diciendo que te devuelva los registros que se crearon hace exactamente un año.

Siguiente el ejemplo anterior, en el cual diste un rango, podrías hacer algo así:

```
def self.before_year
   where(created_at: 1000.years.ago..1.year.ago)
end
```

Sin embargo, esto no es muy elegante (¿por qué 1000 años?). A mi, personalmente me gusta más en este caso escribir directamente SQL:

```
def self.before_year
   where('created_at < ?' 1.year.ago)
end
```

Dicho esto, es probable que en lugar de un método de clase, prefieras definir un scope:

```
scope :before_year, -> { where('created_at < ?' 1.year.ago) }
```

Comment: Saludos @hcarreras tanto el scope como el metodo van fenomenal, solo tengo una curiosidad en cuantoa ello, la idea es que solo se impriman registros del año pasado exactamente, es decir si hoy en 2016, que sean solo registros del 2015 para abajo

Comment: @HectorHernandez prueba con 1.year.ago.beginning_of_year